# Как избежать некорректный ответ от сайта?

Tags: python

Иногда сайт передает мне такой ответ:

```
<html> <head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx/1.15.3</center> </body> </html>
```

из-за этого я не могу парсить с json(),трейсбечит ошибку.
Подскажите,как избежать этот ответ?
Делаю такой запрос:

```
 parseresult = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        print(parseresult.json())
```

Обрабатываю его в json(),и если на сервере ошибка,мне приходит трейсбек.

Comment: На сервере произошла ошибка, о чём Вам и сообщается. Вполне возможно, что Вы передаёте неверный запрос, но я ещё недостаточно силён в телепатии, чтобы узнать как это поправить. Пожалуйста, приведите код, который приводит к такому ответу и краткое описание того, как именно должно всё работать по-вашему мнению.

Comment: Дополнил,посмотрите.Если что-то еще надо поправлю

Comment: Это нужно спрашивать у администратора сайта.